# How to be able to edit one cell in MySQL table with VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have `MySQL` table I added as a `datagridview` from datasource in `VB.NET`. I want the user to be able to edit only one cell in first row in  the last column in the table and block all cells for editing!

Any Idea for this issue?

Comment: Rows, columns and cells all have a `ReadOnly` property. You can either set `ReadOnly` to `True` for every other cell or you can do so for every other row and column and then every other cell in the same row and column.

Answer (score 1):

Set `Readonly` Property True For All Fields Except that Editable Field Does your Job

Comment: I think you mean `True` for all other cells, not `False`.

Comment: S jmcilhinney .. I mistakenly post that

Comment: I made `Readonly` to true for all fields but I didn't find `readonly` for cell...there is only can edit column `readonly` no for cells in properties as I saw..do I need to do it with code?

Comment: You can Set Cell Property in code Also like these `dgMain.Item(1,1).readonly= true` where dgMain Is your datagridview Name